# Typing animation cursor disappears after first item in array is typed

Tags: javascript, html, animation

I am working on a typing animation - it displays how i want in terms of format and words except the cursor animation types the first item as expected, but the cursor disapears once 'item1' is typed. I want the cursor to remain on the screen whilst it types all remaining items and disappear only after the final item has been typed. See below snippet to see what it currently does

```js
var TxtRotate = function (el, toRotate, period, fixedText) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.fixedText = fixedText;
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function () {

    //Stops when text completes
    if (this.loopNum >= this.toRotate.length) return;

    var i = this.loopNum;
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];

    // Get the letter to substring that needs to be appended in the span
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);


    if (this.loopNum === 0) {
        this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.fixedText + ' ' + this.txt + '</span>';
    } else {
        //adds a letter on the screen
        var spacing = '';
        var countSpacing = 0
        while (countSpacing < (this.fixedText.length * 2)) { spacing = spacing + "&nbsp;"; countSpacing++; }
        this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + spacing + this.txt + '</span>';
    }
    var that = this;

    //calculates the time  to wait before writing next letter
    var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;

    // If backspacing reduce it by  half
    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }

    // If the word is complete
    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        //add a delay of 500mx
        delta = 500;
        // add a new line (</br>
        this.el.innerHTML = `<span class="wrap">${this.el.textContent}</br></span>`;
        // add a sibling element to you element
        var next_txt = document.createElement("span");
        // add sibling element to the parent
        this.el.parentNode.appendChild(next_txt);

        // make your self new element, so that it writes into the new element next time
        this.el = next_txt;
        //  pick the next word
        this.loopNum++;
        //clear current txt
        this.txt = '';
    }

    setTimeout(function () {

        that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        var fixedText = elements[i].getAttribute('data-fixed');

        if (toRotate) {
            new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period, fixedText);
        }
    }
    // INJECT CSS
    var css = document.createElement("style");
    css.type = "text/css";
    css.innerHTML = ".txt-rotate > .wrap { border-right: 0.08em solid #666 }";
    document.body.appendChild(css);
};
```

```html
       <h1 class="textsize">
                            <span class="txt-rotate"
                                  data-period="2000"
                                  data-fixed=" We develop"
                                  data-rotate='[ "item1", "item2", "item3", "item4", "item5" , "item6", "item7", "item8"]'></span>
                        </h1>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this on for size. I made the following changes to your code. I removed the last 4 items in your array just to make the animation run faster:

- One of your main problems is that you think you are adding the new span element as a sibling to the "txt-rotate" span, but you aren't, as can be seen in the inspector. So your CSS code that affects ".txt-rotate > .wrap" elements will never do anything to it. I changed the code slightly to use CSS to add a pseudo-element to any .wrap span element. Once the entire word has been written, I remove the "wrap" class.
- As mentioned above, I'm using a pseudo-element for the cursor instead of a border like you had it. but if you need a border you can adjust the CSS.

```js
var TxtRotate = function (el, toRotate, period, fixedText) {
    this.toRotate = toRotate;
    this.el = el;
    this.loopNum = 0;
    this.period = parseInt(period, 10) || 2000;
    this.txt = '';
    this.fixedText = fixedText;
    this.tick();
    this.isDeleting = false;
};

TxtRotate.prototype.tick = function () {
    //Stops when text completes
    var i = this.loopNum;
    if (i >= this.toRotate.length) return; 
    var fullTxt = this.toRotate[i];
    // Get the letter to substring that needs to be appended in the span
    this.txt = fullTxt.substring(0, this.txt.length + 1);
    if (this.loopNum === 0) {
        this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + this.fixedText + ' ' + this.txt + '</span>';
    } else {
        //adds a letter on the screen
        var spacing = '';
        var countSpacing = 0
        while (countSpacing < (this.fixedText.length * 2)) {
         spacing = spacing + "&nbsp;";
          countSpacing++;
        }
        this.el.innerHTML = '<span class="wrap">' + spacing + this.txt + '</span>';
    }
    var that = this;
    //calculates the time to wait before writing next letter
    var delta = 300 - Math.random() * 100;
    // If backspacing reduce it by  half
    if (this.isDeleting) { delta /= 2; }
    // If the word is complete
    if (!this.isDeleting && this.txt === fullTxt) {
        //add a delay of 500mx
        delta = 500;
        // add a new line (</br>
        this.el.innerHTML = `<span>${this.el.textContent}</br></span>`;
        // add a sibling element to you element
        var next_txt = document.createElement("span");
        // add sibling element to the parent
        this.el.parentNode.appendChild(next_txt);
        // make your self new element, so that it writes into the new element next time
        this.el = next_txt;
        //  pick the next word
        this.loopNum++;
        //clear current txt
        this.txt = '';
    }
    setTimeout(function () {
        that.tick();
    }, delta);
};

window.onload = function () {
    var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('txt-rotate');
    for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
        var toRotate = elements[i].getAttribute('data-rotate');
        var period = elements[i].getAttribute('data-period');
        var fixedText = elements[i].getAttribute('data-fixed');
        if (toRotate) {
            new TxtRotate(elements[i], JSON.parse(toRotate), period, fixedText);
        }
    }
 };
```

```css
.wrap::after {
  content: "|";
}
```

```html
<h1 class="textsize">
  <span class="txt-rotate" data-period="2000" data-fixed="We develop" data-rotate='["item1", "item2", "item3", "item4"]'></span>
</h1>
```